# How to make Zoom speakers display at top of screen?

Tags: zoom.us

I don't normally do Zoom meetings where anyone uses video, but today I am. In preparation for this I'm testing a meeting where I am connected 3 times from different machines to check how it all looks. But try as I might, I cannot get the speakers to appear on the top of the screen. They are always in a floating gallery mode, even if I set it to use Standard which according to Zoom should put the speakers in a strip across the top.

How can I get out of this gallery/window mode and just fix the speakers across the top?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.  You can't be in "Full Screen" mode apparently.  If you are, you only get the gallery view on the side or a floating window.  If not in full screen, then you get them across the top.